# Getting user input to create mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

am trying to create a program that gets input from the user and creates a mysql database using the input as the database name, i succeeded in creating the database but only if i input the database name in the code myself, herse what i have so far

```
package mqsljava;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mqsljava {

//CONNECTION

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
     //THE VARIABLE TO STORE USER INPUT
        String Data;
     //SCANNER TO GET USER INPUT
        Scanner Dbname = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your db name");
    //VARIABLE SAVES USER INPUT
    Data = Dbname.nextLine();

    //WHERE THE PROBLEM IS, USING USER INPUT DATA TO CREATE DATABASE

    String EMPLOYEE_DB = " CREATE DATABASE '"+Data+"' ";
        Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      stmt.executeUpdate(EMPLOYEE_DB);
      System.out.println("Database created.");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("error: failed to load MySQL driver.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("error: failed to create a connection object.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("other error:");
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();        
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    }

    }
```

But i keep getting error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Data'' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
    at mqsljava.Mqsljava.main(Mqsljava.java:52)
```

I think am not using the right statement, i tried so many things but still not working

Comment: Have you tried without those single quotes in `'"+Data+"'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create database you don't need to use `'DB_NAME'` you have to use the name without `''` like this :

```
String EMPLOYEE_DB = " CREATE DATABASE " + Data;
```

Like @baao mention in comment, your way is not secure and open to an SQL Injection you have to check the name before you use it in your query.

Comment: Worth to mention that the resulting query will be highly insecure and open to sql injection

Comment: you are welcome @gbolahan don't forgot the SQL Injection you have to secure your data good luck